# Based on Rows Selection Split the Number of Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I have 2 Dropdowns,

One is for number of Links and other for Number of Rows. Based on the Number of Rows Selection the Links have to change the rows.

For eg. if I select the number of Links as 5 and Number of Rows as 3, It means 5 Links have to divided in to 3 Rows

Link count is 5 and Row count is 4 =  **Result should be** first row 3 , second row 2 thrird row 1

Link count is 7 and Row count is 4 = **Result should be** First Rows 4 , Second Row 2 and third is 1

The first row can have maximum of 5 colums.

I have created the fiddle and not sure about the logic any help `https://jsfiddle.net/hnqxe7dc/`

```js
$("#rows").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("#rows option:selected").each(function() {
      str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });

  })
  .change();

$("#nrGames").change(function() {
  var value = +$(this).val();
  var nr = 0;
  var elem = $('#games').empty();
  while (nr < value) {
    elem.append("<li><a href='#'><label for='" + "menuItemId" + "'><input type='checkbox' id='" + "menuItemId" + "' checked='checked' /> Menu Item " + nr + "</label></a></li>");
    nr++;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lable> Select Link</lable>
<select id="nrGames" name="nrGame">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<lable> Select Rows</lable>
<select name="sweets" id="rows">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option selected="selected">4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<div id="games"></div>
```

Comment: if _Link count is 5 and Row count is 4_ then how many links and row are there?

Comment: _“not sure about the logic”_ - me neither; but that is due to that your description is rather lacking. What is the underlying logic of this links-to-rows distribution? You have given a few examples, but not explained at all _how_ those values are achieved.